# How to select specific object in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON Data like below

```
{
"items":
    {
        "item":
            [
                {
                    "id": "0001",
                    "type": "donut",
                    "name": "Cake",
                    "ppu": 0.55,
                    "batters":
                        {
                            "batter":
                                [
                                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                                ]
                        },
                    "topping":
                        [
                            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                        ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "0002",
                    "type": "donut",
                    "name": "Raised",
                    "ppu": 0.55,
                    "batters":
                        {
                            "batter":
                                [
                                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                                ]
                        },
                    "topping":
                        [
                            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                        ]
                }]
   }
  }
```

I want to select `item` object having id `0001`.So how can I select or filter only this single `item` object using javascript or Jquery??

please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: @Dikesh Only single item object means in JSON Array I want only one item object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
var item = data.items.item.filter(function(x){ 
  return x.id === '0001'; 
})[0];
```

Comment: @BrijeshGandhi: jQuery is very simple, if you what to use and when to use ;) anyway , if you have found your ANSWER, then lets close this question.